# Migration from Squarespace to WordPress: Remove leading 0 from %monthnum% in permalinks

Tags: customization, permalinks

I need my WP permalinks display months *without* using any zeros in the URL i.e. /1/ instead of /01/ for January.

I'm moving my blog from Squarespace to Wordpress and I obviously want to keep all my existing URLs intact. Wordpress does a perfect copy of the Squarespace permalinks, with one exception; it shows months as ‘01’ whereas Squarespace shows them as ‘1’.

Current Wordpress permalink: `http://example.com/home/2014/01/30/welcome`

Old Squarespace permalink: `http://example.com/home/2014/1/30/welcome`

i.e. `/1/` instead of `/01/`

Without changing that, I'm guessing that when I point my DNS to my new WP blog, all the links will break.

I've spent the last 3 hours scouring the Wordpress.org support .docs, to no avail.

Help!

Comment: Would you mind explaining the reason behind it? Might help other readers as well as people who try to answer your question.

Comment: Sure. I'm moving my blog from Squarespace to Wordpress and I obviously want to keep all my existing URLs intact.

Wordpress does a perfect copy of the Squarespace permalinks, with the one exception as detailed above.

Without that, I'm guessing that when I point my DNS to my WP blog, all the links to the blog will break.

Comment: Could you please add that as an [edit] to the question? And please show us your research, what you've tried so far and where you failed. Thanks.

Comment: Done! And haven't really ‘tried’ anything so far as I have no idea where to start. I was hoping that I could find a different version of the %monthnum% code that wouldn't display any zeros, but had no luck.

Comment: Yes! That looks like EXACTLY what I need. I'll take a closer look now...